# Unresolved External Symbol (Involves Templates with User-Defined Classes)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am using Visiual Studio 2013. For some reason, I am getting the following error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Word &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVWord@@@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall BST<class Word>::visit(class BSTNode<class Word> *)" (?visit@?$BST@VWord@@@@MAEXPAV?$BSTNode@VWord@@@@@Z) C:\Users\Reuben\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CS321 Lab4\CS321 Lab4\main.obj    CS321 Lab4
```

The error is due to this particular line:

```
BST<Word> tree;
```

If the line were as follows, then it seems to compile just fine:

`BST<int> tree;`OR `BST<string> tree;`

So for some reason, it's not liking my implementation of the Word class I defined. Here is the following code.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Word.h"
#include "genBST.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BST<Word> tree;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Word.h

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Word{
public:
    string* word;
    set<int>* lineNums;
    void addLineNum(int);
    Word(string*, int);
    Word();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Word& pr);
    friend bool operator==(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator!=(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator<(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator<=(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator>=(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator>(Word, Word);
};

Word::Word(string* myWord, int myLineNum) {
    word = myWord;
    set<int>* lineNums = new set<int>();
    lineNums->insert(myLineNum);

}

Word::Word()
{
    word = new string("");
    set<int>* lineNums = new set<int>();
    lineNums->insert(1);
}

void Word::addLineNum(int line)
{
    lineNums->insert(line);
}

//overload comparison operators
//take note that the order of these are important
//since some of the operators are defined in terms of the previously defined ones
bool operator==(Word word1, Word word2)
{
    if (*(word1.word) == *(word2.word))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool operator!=(Word word1, Word word2)
{
    return !(word1 == word2);
}
bool operator<=(Word word1, Word word2)
{
    if (*(word1.word) <= *(word2.word))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool operator<(Word word1, Word word2)
{
    if (word1 <= word2 && word1 != word2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool operator>(Word word1, Word word2)
{
    return !(word1 <= word2);
}
bool operator>=(Word word1, Word word2)
{
    return !(word1 < word2);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Word& word1)
{
    out << *(word1.word);
    out << ": ";
    set<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = word1.lineNums->begin(); it != word1.lineNums->end(); it++)
    {
        out << *it << " ";
    }

    return out;
}
```

The last file is genBST.h. It's a long file, so I'm posting it last. This file was given to me as part of my assignment and we are not allowed to make changes to this file or else we will lose points.

```
//************************  genBST.h  **************************
//                 generic binary search tree

#include <queue>
#include <stack>

#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE

template<class T>
class Stack : public stack<T> {
public:
    T pop() {
        T tmp = top();
        stack<T>::pop();
        return tmp;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Queue : public queue<T> {
public:
    T dequeue() {
        T tmp = front();
        queue<T>::pop();
        return tmp;
    }
    void enqueue(const T& el) {
        push(el);
    }
};
template<class T> class BST;

template<class T>
class BSTNode {
public:
    BSTNode() {
        left = right = 0;
    }
    BSTNode(const T& e, BSTNode<T> *l = 0, BSTNode<T> *r = 0) {
        el = e; left = l; right = r;
    }
    T el;
    BSTNode<T> *left, *right;
};

template<class T>
class BST {
public:
    BST() {
        root = 0;
    }
    ~BST() {
        clear();
    }
    void clear() {
        clear(root);
        root = 0;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const {
        return root == 0;
    }
    void preorder() {
        preorder(root);
    }
    void inorder() {
        inorder(root);
    }
    void postorder() {
        postorder(root);
    }
    void insert(const T&);
    void recursiveInsert(const T& el) {
        recursiveInsert(root, el);
    }
    T* search(const T& el) const {
        return search(root, el);
    }
    T* recursiveSearch(const T& el) const {
        return recursiveSearch(root, el);
    }
    void deleteByCopying(BSTNode<T>*&);
    void findAndDeleteByCopying(const T&);
    void deleteByMerging(BSTNode<T>*&);
    void findAndDeleteByMerging(const T&);
    void iterativePreorder();
    void iterativeInorder();
    void iterativePostorder();
    void breadthFirst();
    void MorrisPreorder();
    void MorrisInorder();
    void MorrisPostorder();
    void balance(T*, int, int);
protected:
    BSTNode<T>* root;
    void clear(BSTNode<T>*);
    void recursiveInsert(BSTNode<T>*&, const T&);
    T* search(BSTNode<T>*, const T&) const;
    T* recursiveSearch(BSTNode<T>*, const T&) const;
    void preorder(BSTNode<T>*);
    void inorder(BSTNode<T>*);
    void postorder(BSTNode<T>*);
    virtual void visit(BSTNode<T>* p)
    {
        cout << p->el << ' ';
    }
};



template<class T>
void BST<T>::clear(BSTNode<T> *p) {
    if (p != 0) {
        clear(p->left);
        clear(p->right);
        delete p;
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::insert(const T& el) {
    BSTNode<T> *p = root, *prev = 0;
    while (p != 0) {  // find a place for inserting new node;
        prev = p;
        if (el < p->el)
            p = p->left;
        else p = p->right;
    }
    if (root == 0)    // tree is empty;
        root = new BSTNode<T>(el);
    else if (el < prev->el)
        prev->left = new BSTNode<T>(el);
    else prev->right = new BSTNode<T>(el);
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::recursiveInsert(BSTNode<T>*& p, const T& el) {
    if (p == 0)
        p = new BSTNode<T>(el);
    else if (el < p->el)
        recursiveInsert(p->left, el);
    else recursiveInsert(p->right, el);
}

template<class T>
T* BST<T>::search(BSTNode<T>* p, const T& el) const {
    while (p != 0)
        if (el == p->el)
            return &p->el;
        else if (el < p->el)
            p = p->left;
        else p = p->right;
        return 0;
}

template<class T>
T* BST<T>::recursiveSearch(BSTNode<T>* p, const T& el) const {
    if (p != 0)
        if (el == p->el)
            return &p->el;
        else if (el < p->el)
            return recursiveSearch(p->left, el);
        else return recursiveSearch(p->right, el);
    else return 0;
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::inorder(BSTNode<T> *p) {
    if (p != 0) {
        inorder(p->left);
        visit(p);
        inorder(p->right);
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::preorder(BSTNode<T> *p) {
    if (p != 0) {
        visit(p);
        preorder(p->left);
        preorder(p->right);
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::postorder(BSTNode<T>* p) {
    if (p != 0) {
        postorder(p->left);
        postorder(p->right);
        visit(p);
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::deleteByCopying(BSTNode<T>*& node) {
    BSTNode<T> *previous, *tmp = node;
    if (node->right == 0)                  // node has no right child;
        node = node->left;
    else if (node->left == 0)               // node has no left child;
        node = node->right;
    else {
        tmp = node->left                  // node has both children;
            previous = node;                  // 1.
        while (tmp->right != 0) {         // 2.
            previous = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->right;
        }
        node->el = tmp->el;               // 3.
        if (previous == node)
            previous->left = tmp->left;
        else previous->right = tmp->left; // 4.
    }
    delete tmp;                            // 5.
}

// findAndDeleteByCopying() searches the tree to locate the node containing
// el. If the node is located, the function DeleteByCopying() is called.

template<class T>
void BST<T>::findAndDeleteByCopying(const T& el) {
    BSTNode<T> *p = root, *prev = 0;
    while (p != 0 && !(p->el == el)) {
        prev = p;
        if (el < p->el)
            p = p->left;
        else p = p->right;
    }
    if (p != 0 && p->el == el)
        if (p == root)
            deleteByCopying(root);
        else if (prev->left == p)
            deleteByCopying(prev->left);
        else deleteByCopying(prev->right);
    else if (root != 0)
        cout << "el " << el << " is not in the tree\n";
    else cout << "the tree is empty\n";
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::deleteByMerging(BSTNode<T>*& node) {
    BSTNode<T> *tmp = node;
    if (node != 0) {
        if (!node->right)           // node has no right child: its left
            node = node->left;     // child (if any) is attached to its parent;
        else if (node->left == 0)   // node has no left child: its right
            node = node->right;    // child is attached to its parent;
        else {                      // be ready for merging subtrees;
            tmp = node->left;      // 1. move left
            while (tmp->right != 0)// 2. and then right as far as possible;
                tmp = tmp->right;
            tmp->right =           // 3. establish the link between the
                node->right;        //    the rightmost node of the left
            //    subtree and the right subtree;
            tmp = node;            // 4.
            node = node->left;     // 5.
        }
        delete tmp;                 // 6.
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::findAndDeleteByMerging(const T& el) {
    BSTNode<T> *node = root, *prev = 0;
    while (node != 0) {
        if (node->el == el)
            break;
        prev = node;
        if (el < node->el)
            node = node->left;
        else node = node->right;
    }
    if (node != 0 && node->el == el)
        if (node == root)
            deleteByMerging(root);
        else if (prev->left == node)
            deleteByMerging(prev->left);
        else deleteByMerging(prev->right);
    else if (root != 0)
        cout << "el " << el << " is not in the tree\n";
    else cout << "the tree is empty\n";
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::iterativePreorder() {
    Stack<BSTNode<T>*> travStack;
    BSTNode<T> *p = root;
    if (p != 0) {
        travStack.push(p);
        while (!travStack.empty()) {
            p = travStack.pop();
            visit(p);
            if (p->right != 0)
                travStack.push(p->right);
            if (p->left != 0)             // left child pushed after right
                travStack.push(p->left); // to be on the top of the stack;
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::iterativeInorder() {
    Stack<BSTNode<T>*> travStack;
    BSTNode<T> *p = root;
    while (p != 0) {
        while (p != 0) {                 // stack the right child (if any)
            if (p->right)                // and the node itself when going
                travStack.push(p->right); // to the left;
            travStack.push(p);
            p = p->left;
        }
        p = travStack.pop();             // pop a node with no left child
        while (!travStack.empty() && p->right == 0) { // visit it and all nodes
            visit(p);                                 // with no right child;
            p = travStack.pop();
        }
        visit(p);                        // visit also the first node with
        if (!travStack.empty())          // a right child (if any);
            p = travStack.pop();
        else p = 0;
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::iterativePostorder() {
    Stack<BSTNode<T>*> travStack;
    BSTNode<T>* p = root, *q = root;
    while (p != 0) {
        for (; p->left != 0; p = p->left)
            travStack.push(p);
        while (p->right == 0 || p->right == q) {
            visit(p);
            q = p;
            if (travStack.empty())
                return;
            p = travStack.pop();
        }
        travStack.push(p);
        p = p->right;
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::breadthFirst() {
    Queue<BSTNode<T>*> queue;
    BSTNode<T> *p = root;
    if (p != 0) {
        queue.enqueue(p);
        while (!queue.empty()) {
            p = queue.dequeue();
            visit(p);
            if (p->left != 0)
                queue.enqueue(p->left);
            if (p->right != 0)
                queue.enqueue(p->right);
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::MorrisInorder() {
    BSTNode<T> *p = root, *tmp;
    while (p != 0)
        if (p->left == 0) {
        visit(p);
        p = p->right;
        }
        else {
            tmp = p->left;
            while (tmp->right != 0 &&// go to the rightmost node of
                tmp->right != p)  // the left subtree or
                tmp = tmp->right;   // to the temporary parent of p;
            if (tmp->right == 0) {   // if 'true' rightmost node was
                tmp->right = p;     // reached, make it a temporary
                p = p->left;        // parent of the current root,
            }
            else {                   // else a temporary parent has been
                visit(p);           // found; visit node p and then cut
                tmp->right = 0;     // the right pointer of the current
                p = p->right;       // parent, whereby it ceases to be
            }                        // a parent;
        }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::MorrisPreorder() {
    BSTNode<T> *p = root, *tmp;
    while (p != 0) {
        if (p->left == 0) {
            visit(p);
            p = p->right;
        }
        else {
            tmp = p->left;
            while (tmp->right != 0 &&// go to the rightmost node of
                tmp->right != p)  // the left subtree or
                tmp = tmp->right;   // to the temporary parent of p;
            if (tmp->right == 0) {   // if 'true' rightmost node was
                visit(p);           // reached, visit the root and
                tmp->right = p;     // make the rightmost node a temporary
                p = p->left;        // parent of the current root,
            }
            else {                   // else a temporary parent has been
                tmp->right = 0;     // found; cut the right pointer of
                p = p->right;       // the current parent, whereby it ceases
            }                        // to be a parent;
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::MorrisPostorder() {
    BSTNode<T> *p = new BSTNode<T>(), *tmp, *q, *r, *s;
    p->left = root;
    while (p != 0)
        if (p->left == 0)
            p = p->right;
        else {
            tmp = p->left;
            while (tmp->right != 0 &&// go to the rightmost node of
                tmp->right != p)  // the left subtree or
                tmp = tmp->right;   // to the temporary parent of p;
            if (tmp->right == 0) {   // if 'true' rightmost node was
                tmp->right = p;     // reached, make it a temporary
                p = p->left;        // parent of the current root,
            }
            else {             // else a temporary parent has been found;
                // process nodes between p->left (included) and p (excluded)
                // extended to the right in modified tree in reverse order;
                // the first loop descends this chain of nodes and reverses
                // right pointers; the second loop goes back, visits nodes,
                // and reverses right pointers again to restore the pointers
                // to their original setting;
                for (q = p->left, r = q->right, s = r->right;
                    r != p; q = r, r = s, s = s->right)
                    r->right = q;
                for (s = q->right; q != p->left;
                    q->right = r, r = q, q = s, s = s->right)
                    visit(q);
                visit(p->left);     // visit node p->left and then cut
                tmp->right = 0;     // the right pointer of the current
                p = p->right;       // parent, whereby it ceases to be
            }                        // a parent;
        }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::balance(T data[], int first, int last) {
    if (first <= last) {
        int middle = (first + last) / 2;
        insert(data[middle]);
        balance(data, first, middle - 1);
        balance(data, middle + 1, last);
    }
}

#endif
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm still learning the basics of c++, I transferred schools so I'm trying to learn c++ (as opposed to Java which is what I was doing before at my other school). Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Oops, I was being dumb, the following line of code:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Word& pr);
```

Should be (I think):

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream, const Word);
```

However, after this change, I still get the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2593: 'operator <<' is ambiguous c:\users\reuben\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\cs321 lab4\cs321 lab4\genbst.h    105 1   CS321 Lab4
```

Where the line 105 refers is the statement in the function (in the genBST.h file):

```
virtual void visit(BSTNode<T>* p)
    {
        cout << p->el << ' ';
    }
```

EDIT v2:
Ok, I've changed the code and it seems to work now. I just placed the implementation of the << operator inside the declaration like so:

```
class Word{
public:
    string* word;
    set<int>* lineNums;
    void addLineNum(int);
    Word(string*, int);
    Word();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Word& word1 )
    {
        out << *(word1.word);
        out << ": ";
        set<int>::iterator it;
        for (it = word1.lineNums->begin(); it != word1.lineNums->end(); it++)
        {
            out << *it << " ";
        }

        return out;
    };
    friend bool operator==(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator!=(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator<(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator<=(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator>=(Word, Word);
    friend bool operator>(Word, Word);
};
```

And it seems to work now.

Comment: What are compiler options?

Comment: I don't know, I'm still new to c++ so I'm using whatever the default is I believe. How would I figure out (and possibly change) the compiler options?

Comment: Try to look it into project setting.

Comment: I found this settings thing (see image: http://puu.sh/ci0rb/6c3753109e.png ). I don't see anything listed as compiler options though.

Comment: If you have only one file, try to compile by command line (Use Visual Studio command prompt) and use compiler cl.

Comment: I have three files however that are dependent on one another.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific linker issue that the OP resolved and is not useful to SO users in general.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that in your class definition you have:

```
class Word{
public:
    string* word;
    set<int>* lineNums;
    void addLineNum(int);
    Word(string*, int);
    Word();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Word& pr);
```

there is no `const` before `Word & pr`

however later in your code you have:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Word& word1)
```

see , there is a const here before Word& word1

should make them same( both have `const`), I think

Comment: hmm, I tried adding that, but I still have the '<< is ambiguous' error

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my Visual Stdio 2010 ( I do not have 2013).
Before I adding the keyword const (before Word & pr) I got same error as you.
However, after I added the const, it was built successfully.

What is the error you got after you add the keyword const ? Post in detail here.

Comment: I did make a small edit to my EDIT, the edit was essentially adding in the "const", although I still had the "<< is ambiguous" error described in the first EDIT. However, see my EDITv2 for my solution to the problem. I'm not quite sure why it works but it does.